# How to know the process PID in linux machine

Tags: linux, java

I am launching an installer from java to install a software on linux, I want to to know the "process id and image name" of it.

In windows I able to get it by using `tasklist` command, but in linux I have not been able to do the same. I tried with `ps -ef` and `ps -A` commands, but its not showing the image name or PID of process.

Is there any command to get it these values?

Answer (score 1):

Most modern Linux distros have handy command `pgrep` (*process grep*), which was created just for this purpose. Use it like this:

```
pgrep -lf programname
```

Unlike naive `ps ax | grep programname`, `pgrep` knows how to not display process id of itself.

There is also complementary utility `pkill`, which can kill process by name (or send other signals).

Comment: I tried it, it didn't worked....... Here the thing is I even don't know the process name, say for example in windows I launched a installer called xxx.exe, then I am able ti see the procee title as "xxx"(window title/process name) with that I am recognizing the windows existance............ In the same way I want to do it for linux(but noprocess existed with title name) Is there any command to get it –

Comment: You should know process name or program name. If you don't, carefully inspect output of `ps ax`. Also, starting `top` or `atop` in another console might shed some light in what is actual process name for the installer - it is most likely to be top process once install begins.

Comment: I want to the know process name of my installer program

Comment: That's what I told you - start `top` in another console, then start your installer, quickly switch back to `top` and watch which process is using most of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

if it is a graphical installer you can run this one-liner in a terminal:

```
ps -fp $(xprop _NET_WM_PID | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

your mouse cursor will change to a crosshair. Now click on the window in question. you should now see process information printed in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ps -aef | grep your_process_name`, replace `your_process_name` with your installer name.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi Alankar, Here the thing is I even don't know the process name, say for example in windows I launched a installer called xxx.exe, then I am able ti see the procee title as "xxx"(window title/process name) with that I am recognizing the windows existance............ In the same way I want to do it for linux(but no process existed with title name) Is there any command to get it

Comment: @kgopi. How you are starting your installer in linux.

Comment: through command prompt like first I am navigating to the installer folder and then I am executing "./xxx.bin" command

Comment: Often (e.g. for NVIDIA drivers) the `*.run` is a huge `sh` script, so with `ps auxw` you see the `sh` process; also `top` will show you all the most active processes...

Comment: @kgopi Then you can give that xxx only after grep something like this `pa -aef | grep -i xxx`

Answer (score 0):

It is generally best to capture the process ID at the time you launch it rather than trying to find it later on.

If using the C API, you get the PID of the spawned process as the return value from [`fork`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/fork/) or [`vfork`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/vfork/) in the mother process.

In a Bourne derived [shell you use `$!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables) immediately after starting it.

Comment: I am using java to launch the installer in linux machine like this runtime.exe("xxx.bin"). so, through java also can i get the PId\process name

Comment: Can't help you much with Java. There are [at least](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834270/how-do-i-obtain-the-pid-of-a-spawned-java-process) two older Stack Overflow threads on [the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284139/how-do-i-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-process-started-in-java), but neither has a really good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are looking for a Linux centric solution rather than a portable one. On Linux the easy, efficient and reliable way to get the information you need from Java is to use the `proc` filesystem, and especially the `/proc/self` directory. The `man 5 proc` manpage describe each file.

The `pid` is first field of `/proc/self/stat`. The image name is the second one.

It is very easy to write a class to wrap these calls. It will be only a few lines of code doing basic IO: fast and robust. Using third party programs is harder to get right and less efficient.

This solution is not portable since most of the Unix systems do not have a `proc` filesystem. You have four options from the best to the worst, IMHO:

- Capture the information you need before starting the process: Could be easy or not depending of your application
- Find clean & system specific implementations like the `proc` file system for Linux
- Use unspecified API. `RuntimeMXBean.getName()` usually returns the `pid`, you can also use reflection to get access to `java.lang.UnixProcess.pid`. Implementation can differs between JVM and can change at any time. Acceptable solutions if you control the environment.
- Write native code to access the POSIX API
- Use external tools like `ps`

If you decide to rely on external tools then you should be very careful about portability (options and output can differs greatly between two OS) and locale settings.